# Update colum according to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to update the column 'montant_dernier_paiement' according to the value of 'n_paiement' and with the value of 'montant_dernier_paiement' where 'is_paiement' = 1 :

[image]

It is not very clear so basically, i would like to set 'montant_dernier_paiement' = 25.78 for rows 8-9-10 and = 13.81 for rows 12-13

Does someone has any ideas/clues ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could try `update yourtable t1 set t1.montant_dernier_paiement = (select max(montant_dernier_paiement) from yourtable t2 group by n_paiement where t2.n_paiement = t1.n_paiement)` (replace yourtable with your table name) i did not test this (please add the database info your are using: eg oracle,mysql..)

Comment: In your example, are you saying you want montant_dernier_paiement = 25.78 where n_patient = 1, and montant_dernier_paiement = 13.81 where n_patient = 2? How does the is_patient column affect this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update q
set montant_dernier_paiement = c.montant_dernier_paiement
from tbl q join tbl c
on c.n_paiement = q.n_paiement and c.is_paiement = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
UPDATE table_name set montant_dernier_paiement = 25.78 WHERE n_paiement = 1

UPDATE table_name set montant_dernier_paiement = 13.81 WHERE n_paiement = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If each `n_paiment` has only one value, then you can use simple window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(montant_dernier_paiment) over (partition by n_paiement) as max_mdp
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set montant_dernier_paiment = max_mdp
    where montant_dernier_paiment <> max_mdp or (montant_dernier_paiment is null and max_mdp is not null);
```

If the above is not true, then what you what is the equivalent of `lag(ignore nulls)`.  SQL Server doesn't support this, but you can use `first_value()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(montant_dernier_paiment) over (partition by n_paiement) as max_mdp,
             first_value(montant_dernier_paiment) over
                 (partition by n_paiement
                  order by (case when montant_dernier_paiment is null then 1 else 2 end) desc,
                            tri desc
                 ) as prev_mdp                     
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set montant_dernier_paiment = prev_mdp
    where montant_dernier_paiment <> prev_mdp or (montant_dernier_paiment is null and prev_mdp is not null);
```

You can also phrase this using `apply`:

```
update t
    set montant_dernier_paiment = t2.montant_dernier_paiment
    from t cross apply
         (select top (1) t.*
          from t t2
          where t2.n_paiement = t.n_paiement and
                t2.tri < t.tri and
                t2.montant_dernier_paiment is not null
          order by t2.tri desc
         ) t2
    where t.montant_dernier_paiment <> t2.montant_dernier_paiment or (t.montant_dernier_paiment is null and t2.montant_dernier_paiment is not null);
```